Recover ETH address wallet
We mistakenly transferred USDT to our BSC address but under ETH Network, after having a chat with the help center, they first provided a looming video to recreate the Safe Wallet address under OP network, which we did, and afterward, we were able to see our funds in the dashboard, but not able to transfer the funds to another wallet or bridge. We tried everything, like clearing the browser and using a different browser. It is now asking to use Safe CLI to execute the transaction, which the Safe Help Center also confirms.
I am a non-tech person and don't know how to use Safe CLI, Devs. Can you please help me with this?
Recreated SafeWallet address - https://app.safe.global/home?safe=eth:0xF845b978FC251d850811b08a2F52D70971492550
Thanks and Regards
Andy.

I‘ve seen your wallet contract with usdt&&usdc on eth mainnet. I think you can execute a transaction on etherscan to withdraw to your eoa wallet and then cross to bsc chain. The devs in safe.global would teach you how to interact with their contract.
